# File path in the Matlab system() function

Tags: python-2.7, matlab

I use Matlab R2017a on Linux. I need to call a Python script from my Matlab script, so I use **system()** function :

```
system('export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ && python /home/user/EEG_data/transformCoordinates.py');
```

It works well, but if I need to make the path of my Python script more generic and I save it in the variable, it doesn't work :

```
eegdata_path = '/home/user/EEG_data'; 
py_path = [eegdata_path '/transformCoordinates.py'];
system('export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ && python py_path');
```

I get this error message :

> python: can't open file 'py_path': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

I did not manage to find how I could pass the file path to the **system()** Matlab function. Could you help me please?

Comment: Try `system(strcat('export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ && python',py_path))`

Comment: Thank you! It did not work directly in system() function, but it did work like this :
    `command = ['export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ && python ' py_path];
    system(command);`